# SendGrid is not sending the email if i used the SMTP configuration to send out email(text/html)

Tags: java, spring, email, smtp, sendgrid

I am using the below configuration to send the email(MimeMessagePreparator).

```
 - spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8 spring.mail.host=smtp.sendgrid.net
   spring.mail.username=SEND-GRID-USER-NAME
   spring.mail.password=SEND-GRID-PASSWORD spring.mail.port=587
   spring.mail.protocol=smtp spring.mail.test-connection=true
   spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
   spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

But send grid is not sending the email to corresponding users.

```
@Async
    @Override
    public Future<Boolean> sendEmailNotification(EmailTemplateDTO emailTemplateDTO) {
        boolean flag = false;
        if (emailTemplateDTO != null) {
            final String emailContent = mailContentBuilder.buildEmailContent(emailTemplateDTO.getObj(),
                    emailTemplateDTO.getEmailTemplate());
            MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
                MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true,
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
                messageHelper.setSubject(emailTemplateDTO.getEmailTemplate().getSubject());
                messageHelper.setFrom(fromEmail);
                messageHelper.setTo(emailTemplateDTO.getTo().stream().toArray(String[]::new));
                messageHelper.setText(emailContent, true);
                final Resource fileResource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:static/logo.png");
                messageHelper.addInline(EmailConstants.XXXX.getName(), fileResource);
            };
            try {
                mailSender.send(messagePreparator);
                flag = true;
            } catch (MailException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return new AsyncResult<>(flag);
        }
        return new AsyncResult<>(flag);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share stack trace ?

Comment: I could not see any exception or error.And i can see in send-grid dash board the requests i made from my application.